# Scroll ListView to coordinates of click, like QQ

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll

I want to scroll to specific item depending upon where user has clicked. All my items of list view are of different heights. Please see the image below.

[image: Example Image]

So if user clicks on the list item 1, lets suppose, so it's bottom should be scrolled till the top of the softkeyboard.

Heights of items and keyboard vary. I have tried `getTop`, `getHeight`, `getMeasuredHeight` but nothing has been working so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Distance Formula]

**Main point is to find the distance between the clicked UI and your keyboard top.**

This is the distance formula. You can achieve your functionality using this. You need

- Clicked Coordinates
- Coordinates of your listview item
- Height of your listview item

Suppose following is your ListView, that is being clicked

```
int[] loc = new int[2];
lvItem_button.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
```

Put a layout at the bottom of your layout, mark your activity as `AdjustPan` in `Android Manifest`, now it will always be at the top of keybaord, when ever the keyboard will open.

Get it's coordinates the same way.

```
int[] cords= new int[2];
keyboard_top_layout.getLocationOnScreen(cords);


double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((cords[0] - loc[0]), 2) + Math.pow((cords[1] - loc[1]), 2));

distance -= heightOfItem; //subtract height because we want to align bottom of item to top of keyboard



distance = Math.ceil(distance);
lvItem.smoothScrollBy((int) -distance, 500); //-distance because X is increasing at bottom and decreasing at top. 500 is delay in scrolling. so it's smooth scroll
```

All done :)